# Varnish 4 does not honor Cache-Control: must-revalidate

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm trying to make Varnish work with last-modified headers, but no matter what I do my page is cached during 120s, and Varnish never revalidate with the backend.

My backend is sending these headers :

```
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, public, stale-while-revalidate=0
Last-Modified: Fri, 22 Jan 2016 03:32:33 GMT
```

And when I log the TTL of the object on hit, it's value is always set to 120s.

I am using **the default VCL** config of Varnish 4.

Regards,

---

Edit: After some search, I found that 120s is the default ttl value of Varnish. But why is he ignoring last-modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer from the Varnish mailing list, in order to emulate the "must-revalidate" header, this piece of VCL must be added:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (beresp.http.cache-control ~ "must-revalidate") {
        set beresp.ttl = 1s;
        set beresp.grace = 0s;
        set beresp.keep = 1w;
    }
}
```

It only works on Varnish 4.

I quote the reason for the 1s ttl :

> This way, you'd only cache for 1 second (don't set it to 0, or all the
>   requests for this object would be done sequentially), but will keep
>   the object for a week, revalidating it each time it is requested and
>   its ttl is expired.

Comment: Here is a thought: 
With 'grace' set to 0 and 'keep' to 1 week every request will hit the backend and have to wait for a response from the backend. In addition to this if the backend server is down nothing is delivered.
If instead you set grace to 1w than during grace time a request is immediately answered and Varnish will retrieve the latest information from the backend for the next request. Plus if the backend server is down the cached value is still delivered.

Comment: The origin's response seems to be indicating that *every* request must be revalidated ("proxy-revalidate" and "stale-while-revalidate=0"), so sending the cached version isn't being allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Set the "s-maxage" or "max-age" attributes of the Cache-Control header:

> beresp.ttl is initialized with the first value it finds among:
>
> ```
> The s-maxage variable in the Cache-Control response header field
> The max-age variable in the Cache-Control response header field
> The Expires response header field
> The default_ttl parameter.
> ```

See: http://book.varnish-software.com/4.0/chapters/VCL_Built_in_Subroutines.html#the-initial-value-of-beresp-ttl